# CouchDB Server Installation Unmet Dependecies - Broken Packages

Tags: dependencies, server, couchdb

From the root directory,

I uninstalled couchDB on a server with:

```
sudo apt-get purge couchdb
```

Installing couchDB on a server with:

```
sudo apt-get install couchdb -y
```

I get the error:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies. couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So, I tried:

```
 sudo apt-get clean
 sudo apt-get install -f 
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
 sudo apt-get update
```

Then,

```
 sudo apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -f
 sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:couchdb/stable
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -f
```

I get the error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies. couchdb-bin : Depends: erlang-abi-15.b E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried,

```
   sudo apt-get remove erlang-abi-15.b
```

I get error:

Virtual packages like 'erlang-abi-15.b' can't be removed

So I do:

```
   sudo apt-get install erlang-abi-15.b
```

I get error:

Package erlang-abi-15.b is a virtual package provided by: erlang-base-hipe 1:17.3 [Not candidate version] erlang-base 1:17.4 [Not candidate version] erlang-base 1:17.1 [Not candidate version] erlang-base-hipe 1:17.3.2 [Not candidate version] erlang-base 1:17.3 [Not candidate version] erlang-base-hipe 1:17.1 [Not candidate version] erlang-base-hipe 1:17.4 [Not candidate version] erlang-base 1:17.3.2 [Not candidate version] erlang-base-hipe 1:16.b.3-dfsg-1ubuntu2.1 [Not candidate version] erlang-base 1:16.b.3-dfsg-1ubuntu2.1 [Not candidate version] erlang-base-hipe 1:16.b.3-dfsg-1ubuntu2 [Not candidate version] erlang-base 1:16.b.3-dfsg-1ubuntu2 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'erlang-abi-15.b' has no installation candidate

So I try:

```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
```

And try installing couchDB again with

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:couchdb/stable -y
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -yf
  sudo apt-get install couchdb -y
```

And I get the same error:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies. couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed

I'm running erlang version 18 (the latest).

I don't know what else to do, help would be appreciated. I think I have been as thorough as possible with this.